# 'User' object has no attribute 'get_all_permissions'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

- What is the cause of this error? I got this error after changing the
  admin style 'User' object has no attribute 'get_all_permissions'  plz help me. (What is the cause of this error? I got this error after changing the
  admin style 'User' object has no attribute 'get_all_permissions'  plz help me. )

  ```
   class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
          def create_user(self, email, username, full_name, phone, password):
              if not email:
                  raise ValueError('plz input email')
              if not username:
                  raise ValueError('plz input username')
              if not full_name:
                  raise ValueError('plz input full_name')
              if not phone:
                  raise ValueError('plz input phone')

              user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), username=username, full_name=full_name, phone=phone)
              user.set_password(password)
              user.save(using=self._db)
              return user

          def create_superuser(self, email, username, full_name, phone, password):
              user = self.create_user(email, username, full_name, phone, password)
              user.is_admin = True
              user.is_superuser = True
              user.save(using=self._db)
              return user


      class User(AbstractBaseUser):
          email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
          username = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
          full_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
          phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
          address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
          is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
          is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
          is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
          permission = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name='users')
          USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
          REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'full_name', 'phone']
          objects = UserManager()

          def __str__(self):
              return self.email

          def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
              return self.is_superuser

          def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
              return self.is_superuser

          @property
          def is_staff(self):
              return self.is_admin
  ```

Comment: Please include your traceback. There's no code here that tries to access a `get_all_permissions` attribute of a user.

Comment: You need to implement a `get_all_permissions` in your `User` model, this looks like: https://github.com/django/django/blob/5fcfe5361e5b8c9738b1ee4c1e9a6f293a7dda40/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L284

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i try to implement something like u sugest, but i given an error, when u have little time i aprecciate some tips : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70731384/custom-user-return-empty-get-all-permissions?noredirect=1#comment125044013_70731384

Answer (score 4):

Add these codes to your model.py

1. Import PermissionsMixin from Django contrib Auth

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
   ```
2. Then change

   ```
   class Account(AbstractBaseUser):

    to

   class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   ```

Then it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning self.is_superuser,
return self.is_admin

```
def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
            return self.is_admin

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
            return self.is_admin
```

will work I hope. :-) It's been one and half a year.